# create a table and different columns within that table based on input of other columns using python

Tags: python

I have been working on a python code to try to create the output below in the python terminal. Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is I want the user to input the numbers for Columns A and B, then the code outputs Columns C, D and E. In Column C, I show how I want the python code to compute that particular column and so on (in other words, I don't want it to actually show "2 + 3 = 5", but I only want it to show 5. That's only to show you how I'm calculated it). Also, at the bottom of the code, I am trying to calculate and print the averages of Columns C and D.

I have been struggling with this for quite some time. Below is the example of how I want the output to be and also the code that I have. Sorry in advance for the code. Some things I know how to do and other things I don't which is why I am asking the Python community for help. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
def solve(columnA, columnB):

   print("   Class    ColumnA    ColumnB    ColumnC    ColumnD    ColumnE")
   i = 0
   columnC = columnB
   columnD = columnC - columnB
   columnE = []
   empty1 = []
   empty2 = []
   empty3 = []
   while(i < len(columnA)):
       columnC += columnB[i]
       print("str(i + 1) + " " + str(columnA[i]) + " " + str(columnB) + \
                        " " + str(columnC) + " " + str(columnD) + " " + 
str(columnE))")
    empty1.append(columnC)
    empty2.append(columnD)
    empty2.append(columnE)
    i += 1
return (empty1, empty2, empty3)
np = int(input("Enter the number of Classes:  "))
column_A = []
column_B = []
for i in range(np):
    column_A.append(int(input("Enter the numbers for Column A  " + str(i + 1) + ": 
    ")))
    column_B.append(int(input("Enter the numbers for Column B  " + str(i + 1) + ": 
    ")))
lis = solve(column_A, column_B)
print("Average of Column C:  " + str(sum(lis[0]) / len(lis[0])))
print("Average of Column D:  " + str(sum(lis[1]) / len(lis[1])))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```py
import itertools
import statistics

number_of_classes = int(input("Enter the number of Classes: "))

def ask_numbers(name, amount_to_ask):
    print('Please enter the numbers for Column', name)
    for how_many_asked_yet in range(amount_to_ask):
        yield (int(input(f'{how_many_asked_yet + 1}) ')))
    print()

columns_names = ('A', 'B')

columns = {name: tuple(ask_numbers(name, number_of_classes)) for name in columns_names}

def compute_c_values(source_column):
    values_accumulator = zip(source_column, itertools.accumulate(source_column))
    current_value, previous_value  = next(values_accumulator)
    yield (f'{current_value}', current_value)
    
    for current_value, sum_value in values_accumulator:
        yield (f'{previous_value}+{current_value}={sum_value}', sum_value)
        previous_value = sum_value

columns['C'] = tuple(compute_c_values(columns['A']))

columns['D'] = tuple(c_value - b_value for (b_value, (_, c_value)) in zip(columns['B'], columns['C']))

columns['E'] = tuple(0 if d_value < 0 else 1 for d_value in columns['D'])

output_header_footer_format = "{:6} | {:10} | {:10} | {:15} | {:10} | {:10}"
print(output_header_footer_format.format('Class', 'Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C', 'Column D', 'Column E'))
print('-------|------------|------------|-----------------|------------|-----------')

output_line_format  = "{0:6} | {1:10} | {2:10} | {3[0]:^15} | {4:10} | {5:^10}"

for class_nb, output_values in enumerate(zip(*columns.values())):
    print(output_line_format.format(class_nb, *output_values))

print(output_header_footer_format.format('', '', '', '', '', ''))

averages = {
    'C' : statistics.mean(c_value for (_, c_value) in columns['C']),
    'D' : statistics.mean(columns['D'])
}
print(output_header_footer_format.format('' , '', 'Averages =', averages['C'], averages['D'], ''))
```

To fully understand this code you will need to read about:

- [Generators](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/classes.html#generators)
- [Generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions)
- [Dictionary comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)
- [.format() method of string objects](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method)
- [Tuples unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)
- [Unpacking Argument List](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)